# wso2is/lib/endorsed/._* not letting java load

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Downloaded from wso2 site the Identity server to my mac.
made copy and executed :
/bin/wso2server.sh -Dstartup
and I get :
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/bpatton/wso2is-5.3.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file /home/bpatton/wso2is-5.3.0/lib/endorsed/._geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.0.jar

It's not a permissions issue chmod -R 0755 
so when I do a strings /lib/endorsed ._geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.0.jar
I get :
Mac OS X
ATTR
com.apple.quarantine

All the .files in lib/endorsed have the same thing in them, all the same size
I tried deleting them and get : 
[bpatton@wso2-dev] wso2is-5.3.0 # bin/wso2server.sh -Dstartup
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/bpatton/wso2is-5.3.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
[2017-06-08 08:47:22,134] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer} -  Error occured while deploying bundles in the dropins directory
...  This question widget thins the output from the execution is code.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.openjpa.osgi.PersistenceActivator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Does the site see that I'm downloading from a mac an give me a mac version?
This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED
The entire problem was in creating my tarball.
I have used
tar -cvf .tar 
for over 35 years and have never had a problem.
from the man pages
man tar
the -f adds an archive.
So every directory has a . file for each file.
These . files were causing the problem.
when I used rsync to transfer between my mac and the Linux VM the problem went away.